# Post action method keep loading in browser without respond from server ,but in background it runs successfully?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am working in Asp.net MVC project and IIS, in localhost every thing work good but when host on server some pages when click on save button it will appear that the browser processing (loading) but in background  it saved successfully.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, DepartmentInput input, FormCollection form)
    {
        ISession session = SessionManager.GetSession();
        var department = session.Get<Department>(id);

        foreach (CultureInfo culture in ApplicationSettings.SupportedCultures)
        {
            string translatedName = form["name" + culture.LCID];
            if (translatedName.IsEmpty())
                ModelState.AddModelError("name" + culture.LCID, ValidationStrings.Required.FormatWith(FormTexts.NameWithLanguage.FormatWith(culture.NativeName)));
            else
                department.Name.SetPhrase(translatedName, culture);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Mapper.Map(input, department);
            session.Update(department);
            TempData[Constants.SUCCESS_MSG_KEY] = DepartmentTexts.Message_DepartmentUpdatedSuccessfully;
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id });
        }

        var model = new ManageDepartmentViewModel
        {
            ParentDepartment = department.Parent,
            Input = department.MapTo<DepartmentInput>()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, can you tell us what you have tried already? Have you checked the network tab of your browser (F12 - Network). This might give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use remote debug to make sure it return view has work well. Detials, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019). Besides, I suggest you could try to enable the [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) to find out which module has block the process.